# Does 'Pending Contact Request' under a contact in skype mean that they have blocked me?

Tags: skype

Ive got several contacts in Skype that are showing up as 'Pending Contact Request' as per the image below, some just have the place holder image as their profile picture, some actually still have a profile pic.

I have spoken to all these people previously on skype so at one time i was a contact of theirs.

Does this mean that they have blocked me on their end ?

[image: skype screenshot]

Comment: Version 6.19 (452) - mac osx

Comment: The users has removed you from their Skype list so only it is showing as pending contact

Comment: As Skype is a desktop app, your question is probably more suitable over at [SU].

Comment: Yes, it may mean that. If they blocked you their client is just ignoring any messages/contact requests from you, but on your side you can still send them.

Answer (score 1):

Pending request - It means that the person has just **removed** you from their Skype **contact list** but **hasn't blocked** you.
You can however **send** them **messages** to them but can't call them.
The person **can call you** if they want.
You can **send** friend **request** again, if they removed you from contact list by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to see the pending requests, try this:

1. Add them to the list which are pending
2. Sign out in order to try with the App mobile
3. Uninstall the App Skype (on the mobile)
4. Install again once you uninstalled it.
5. Sign same account which you signed with the laptop, tablet, or computer (windows)
6. Delete all the contacts you added when they were on pending.
7. Log in to the main account which you logged out initially and check if are still or not.

I tried it and it worked for me.

Comment: Hi daniele, welcome to SuperUser. While this might remove the pending request, that wasn't what the OP asked. They were looking to find out if it meant they had been blocked, which your answer doesn't cover.

Comment: I am sorry if twasn't the answer you asked but still this might need for others, but I'll try to give the answer.
Well definitely if it shows pending requests perhaps they have removed you from their lists of contact. You may send the messages but you can't call.

They might receive your message but unable to receive your calls. Well sometimes they receive calls rarely.

You can always re-add them on your list of contact if you want to, but it doesn't always get to happen. Thanks.


Hope you found the good answer take care.

Bye☺

Answer (score -1):

Good morning

I was having the same problem. I am managing an Office 365 account for the company that I am working for. The setting to allow external communications was checked; and even then, I could not connect.

The external contact was showing a pending status. I finally realized that there was not a function using the regular Skype app in windows 10 that would allow me to see the request and accept it.

Solution: The person who needs to accept the contact request has to sign in to skype online. Then and only then, that person will be able to accept the request. After doing so, I was able to communicate with my personal account (regular Skype) using the company's Skype for business account.